# change requireJS from adding the .js file extension automatically on intern.js

Tags: requirejs, amd, intern, marko

Currently I am working in custom html reporter for intern.js. The Templating engine that i am using is marko.js.
marko.js have extension file with ".marko" for me to input my html syntax
The file is generated correctly in normal node.js (common.js)

The issue occurred when i integrate the same code to intern.js. The requirejs(AMD) that use by internjs is adding the .js file extension automatically to my marko extension when i do

```
var template = require('./hello-world.marko');
```

which make the file become `hello-world.marko.js` and this caused the code broke in markojs

the custom html reporter code is below

```
define(function (require) {

    // require('intern/dojo/node!marko/node-require').install();
    var fs = require('intern/dojo/node!fs');

    var template = require('./hello-world.marko');
    console.log(template);
    function JsonReporter(config) {
        config = config || {};
        this.output = config.output;
    }

    JsonReporter.prototype = {
        runEnd(executor) {
            // console.log("toJson: " + JSON.stringify(executor.suites))
            data = JSON.stringify(executor.suites);
            template.renderToString(data,
                function (err, output) {
                    console.log(output);
                    fs.writeFile('result.html', output, function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                        console.log('Save done');
                    });
                });
        },
    }
    return JsonReporter;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require` function isn't really meant for loading arbitrary text resources in either Node's loader or an AMD loader. In Node, whether you're running Intern or not, you can use `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync`. In Intern's Dojo-based AMD environment you can also use the `dojo/text` loader plugin, like this:

```
var template = require('dojo/text!./hello-world.marko');
```